# Cannot call read on std::net::TcpStream due to unsatisfied trait bounds

Tags: rust

SOLUTION:
I needed to add "use std::io::prelude::*;" to my code. I do not know why.

I am trying to read from an std::net::TcpStream but I recieve this error when calling stream.read(&buf).unwrap;

> the method `read` exists for struct `std::net::TcpStream`, but its
> trait bounds were not satisfied method cannot be called on
> `std::net::TcpStream` due to unsatisfied trait bounds note: the
> following trait bounds were not satisfied:
> `std::net::TcpStream: futures::AsyncRead`
> which is required by `std::net::TcpStream: futures::AsyncReadExt` help: items from traits can only be used if the
> trait is in scoperustc(E0599) main.rs(31, 16): method cannot be called
> on `std::net::TcpStream` due to unsatisfied trait bounds tcp.rs(49,
> 1): doesn't satisfy `std::net::TcpStream: futures::AsyncReadExt`
> tcp.rs(49, 1): doesn't satisfy `std::net::TcpStream: futures::AsyncRead` mod.rs(580, 8): the method is available for
> `std::boxed::Box<std::net::TcpStream>` here

Code:

```
use irc::client::prelude::*;
use futures::prelude::*;
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr, TcpStream};
use std::io;
use futures::{AsyncRead, AsyncReadExt};

const NAME: &str = "nickname";

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DCC {
    ip: IpAddr,
    port: u16,
}

impl DCC {
    fn from_msg(msg: &str) -> Result<DCC, std::num::ParseIntError> {
        let msg_split: Vec<&str> = msg.split_whitespace().collect();
        let ip: u32 = msg_split[3].parse()?;
        let ip_addr: IpAddr = IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::from(ip));
        let port_num: u16 = msg_split[4].parse()?;
        let dcc = DCC{
           ip: ip_addr,
           port: port_num,
        };
        return Ok(dcc);
    }
    async fn connect(&self) -> Result<(), io::Error>{
        let socket_addr = SocketAddr::new(self.ip, self.port);
        let mut socket = TcpStream::connect(socket_addr)?;
        let mut buf = vec![];
        socket.read(&buf).unwrap();
        return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "oh no!"));
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn irc_get(name: &str) -> Result<String, irc::error::Error>{
    let config = Config {
        nickname: Some(NAME.to_owned()),
        server: Some("irc.irchighway.net".to_owned()),
        port: Some(6667),
        use_tls: Some(false),
        channels: vec!["#ebooks".to_owned()],
        ..Config::default()
    };
    let mut client = Client::from_config(config).await?;
    client.identify()?;

    
    let mut stream = client.stream()?;

    //waits for server to log us in and then sends the search request
    loop{ 
        let m = match stream.next().await{
            Some(v) => v,
            None => panic!("at the disco")
        };
        let message = match &m {
                 Ok(message) => match &message.command {Command::NOTICE(_s1, s2)=> {print!("{:?} \n", s2); message}, _ => message},
                Err(_e) => panic!("at the disco")};
        match &message.command{
            Command::NOTICE(_s, msg) => { if msg.contains("Welcome to #ebooks"){break}}, 
            _=> ()    
        }          
    }
    client.send_privmsg("#ebooks", format!["@Search {}", name])?;
    loop{
        let m = match stream.next().await.transpose()?{
            Some(m) => m,
            None => panic!("at the disco")
        };
        match &m.command{
            Command::PRIVMSG(nm, msg) => if nm == NAME {println!("{:?}",m); return Ok(String::from(msg))},
            _ => ()
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let dcc = DCC::from_msg(&irc_get(&"romeo and juliet").unwrap()[..]);
    println!("{:?}", dcc);
}
```

I'm fairly new at rust and based on all of the examples in the documentation I think I'm using .read correctly. My only thought is that maybe it's because I'm trying to write the code in the impl, but I don't know if rust treats that differently. It also fails with "async fn connect..." and with "fn connect...".

Comment: It's hard to know what you're doing without a minimal reproduction example, and at the very east the *entire* error message*. But you seem to be mixing synchronous and asynchronous APIs which doesn't help. One very relevant thing in Rust is that *trait methods require the trait to be in scope*. `read` might be a method on `Read` (if using a sync tcp stream from the standard library) or on `AsyncRead` (via `AsyncReadExt`). The corresponding trait(s) need to be imported explicitely (possibly via a "prelude import" but I dislike that in long-term cases) in order for the method to be accessible.

Comment: Edited question with full error message and all my code (including the new import statement suggested in the answer below (which did not fix the error)).

Comment: This is also not my first rust project, I already built a complet web application backend with user login and postgressql. So while I am new, I am at least familiar with rust and I have read just under half of the rustbook so far.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler was telling you the solution:

> help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope

You need to import the traits in order to use them:

```rust
use futures::{AsyncRead, AsyncReadExt};
```

Also you would probably want to use [`tokio::TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.5.0/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html) which is async and not the `std` one.

Comment: I added that and it did not fix it. I have edited my question with an unabridged error message which seems to claim that the error is in the TcpStream itself. That however seems ...unlikely.

Comment: @aghayes, I added that you may need tokio one instead of std for async.